# How to fix the warnings while converting .aar file to .dll in xamarin as it is not generating all the required classes/interfaces

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to convert .aar file to .dll file in xamarin, it is not generating all the required classes/interfaces and giving me attached warnings.I have checked all the SDK and API level, they are all correct

When I tried .aar file in android studio project it works fine there

[image: error]

Comment: You will have will manually edit a transforms file that helps the convertor make the proper Java to C# transformations :  https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to edit transform file as I am very new to it.